# How to compute average of 2 depth textures by blending?

Tags: opengl, textures

I need to compute the average of two depth textures at each pixel.  I expect I could do that with a GLSL fragment shader, but I'd prefer a solution that works on the dumbest possible hardware, so I tried blending.  Here's the main code:

```
/// Initialize color buffer to black
glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

// Turn off unnecessary operations
glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
glDisable( GL_LIGHTING );
glDisable( GL_CULL_FACE );
glDisable( GL_BLEND );
glDisable( GL_STENCIL_TEST );
glDisable( GL_DITHER );

// Set all matrices to identity
glMatrixMode( GL_TEXTURE );
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();

glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE );
RenderAQuadTexturedWith( texture1 );

glEnable( GL_BLEND );
glBlendEquation( GL_FUNC_ADD );
glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
glColor4f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f );

RenderAQuadTexturedWith( texture2 );
```

The problem is that the values I'm getting are off by around 0.002, as compared with what I get by getting the pixels of the two textures and computing the average on the CPU.  When a set a breakpoint in OpenGL Profiler (this is on Mac OS X 10.6.8) and eyeball the color buffer, it looks about like what I'd expect.  Is there some inherent inaccuracy in blend mode?

I also tried setting the current color to 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 and using `glBlendFunc( GL_ONE, GL_ONE )`, and the errors were in the opposite direction but about the same magnitude.

EDIT TO ADD:  In retrospect, I see my mistake clearly: If I render into a render buffer with 8 bits per color component, and then read pixels from one of those components, then I only have 8 bits of accuracy.

So now I need to figure out a way to extract the results without losing accuracy.  Maybe a fragment shader that sets `gl_FragDepth`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I added to my question, the root of the problem was not with depth textures or blend mode, but just that I was rendering into a buffer with 8 bits per color component.  It probably would work if I went out of my way to get a higher-precision color buffer.  But I went for the alternative of using a fragment program that puts the output in `gl_FragDepth`, and that seems to work as desired, since I already had a 24-bit depth buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The GPU does all calculations in `float`. Check that your CPU reference is also using `float` and not `double`.

Comment: No, I'm not using doubles.  Anyway, if it were a float vs. double issue, wouldn't you expect to see differences in the sixth or seventh decimal place, not the third?

Comment: If the texture values range is 0-255, then the sixth digit is at 0.002.

Comment: I don't see why the texture values would range 0-255.  When I create the texture objects, I pass `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` for the `format` and `internalFormat` parameters, and OpenGL Profiler shows the internal format as `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24`.  Maybe something funny happens when a depth texture is interpreted as luminance?

Comment: @JWWalker: How do you cause a depth to be interpreted as luminance? Unless you do glReadPixels/glTexSubImage calls, that's not possible. And if you try that, your luminance values will be subject to the space limitations for storing luminance values. Which is typically 8-bit, unless you specify a larger luminance format. Maybe that's the code you should post.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: my remark about "interpreted as luminance" refers to the fact that `GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE` defaults to `GL_LUMINANCE`, so just drawing with a depth texture treats it as luminance.

Comment: @JWWalker: I'd forgotten about that; I haven't used the fixed-function pipeline in years. However, there's little said about the precision of such values, which leads me to believe that it is at least somewhat hardware-dependent. So a compression to bytes at some point along the line is not unreasonable. Also, you should _always_ use sized internal formats (GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24 rather than just GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT).